# Implementing Step Line Chart in Dynamic Data Display

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic-data-display

I would like to have a step line chart like this one, using [D3](http://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com/)

[image]

I think it is not available in D3. I guess I will have to code it as an add-in. 
However I really do not know where to start from, so any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found a nice way to do it [here](http://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com/discussions/73905)